# "failed to open stream" error when executing "migrate:make"

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, octobercms

I am trying to create a simple database migration. But when I run the following command in the root directory of my project:

```
php artisan migrate:make --create=users create_users_table
```

I get the following error:

[ErrorException]

> file_put_contents(/var/www/blog/app/database/migrations/2015_12_20_052832_create_users_table.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I am using the latest version of OctoberCMS and am getting the same error both on `Linux` and `Windows`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is wrong for the latest version of OctoberCMS. To create a new migration, you should run this:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

Also, you should create the path of migrations because it does not created at the installation of OctoberCMS.

```
# execute from the root app folder
mkdir -p database/migrations
```

Comment: But running `php artisan help migrate:make` gives me another usage: `migrate:make [--bench[="..."]] [--create[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--table[="..."]] name`

Comment: At the latest version of OctoberCMS, the `migrate:make` command does not exist.

Comment: Umm, you are right, the version of OctoberCMS I have installed on my linux seems to be old. But I was getting the exact same error on the latest version of `OctoberCMS` that I recently installed on my Windows. The problem is probably that `database/migrations` doesn't exist. I will check it and will keep you posted.